# il solo/più etc. che + indicative?

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood, tenses

I have learnt French but not much Italian. In French when you have the phrase "the only/the most/the best which..." the relative clause is in the subjunctive.

For example, "the best book I've read" would be "le meilleur livre que **j'aie** lu". This is in the subjunctive.

Is it not the case in Italian? Is the correct translation "il miglior libro che **ho** letto"?

Comment: Not a full answer. To my ear, “il miglior libro che ho letto” is a matter-of-fact statement, so indicative mood. Not that the subjunctive would be wrong, of course. If I add “mai”, the subjunctive becomes, at least to my ear, mandatory: “il miglior libro che abbia mai letto”.

Comment: I find acceptable also *Il miglior libro che ho mai letto.* although by default I use the subjunctive.

Answer (score -1):

The correct phrase is actually with conjunctive, but it is often misspelled by Italians themselves. The correct translation is *il miglior libro che abbia mai letto*, *abbia* being in conjunctive, just like in French.